# Drag and Drop - multiple items and prevent duplication

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-sortable

Good Morning All,
I'm in need of your help with a client side issue\question that I'm having. What I've built so far is a drag and drop solution (using jquery/jquery ui) that will allow you drag and drop multiple items from one container to another. Each time you click on a item (which is represented as a li html element) jquery adds the class '.selected' which will change the text color to red. What I need to is prevent dropping a duplicate item(s)  into any container(this is represented as a ul html element) and to help remove the .selected class from each item(s) after the item(s) is dropped into a container.

The link provided below is an example of my code.
http://codepen.io/brandonmichaelhunter/full/fFiIc

Thank you in advance.

```
/* [JAVASCRIPT] */

function GetSecurityDetails() {
    var secObjs = [];
    var secObj = new Object();
    secObj.GroupName = "Group1"
    secObj.GroupID = 1;
    secObj.UserName = "Brandon M. Hunter";
    secObj.UserEmail = "bhunter@gmail.com";
    secObj.UserID = 1;
    secObjs.push(secObj);

    var secObj = new Object();
    secObj.GroupName = "Group1"
    secObj.GroupID = 1;
    secObj.UserName = "Brandon I. Hunter";
    secObj.UserEmail = "bhunterI@gmail.com";
    secObj.UserID = 2;
    secObjs.push(secObj);

    var secObj = new Object();
    secObj.GroupName = "Group1"
    secObj.GroupID = 1;
    secObj.UserName = "Cameron M. Hunter";
    secObj.UserEmail = "chunter@gmail.com";
    secObj.UserID = 3;
    secObjs.push(secObj);

    var secObj = new Object();
    secObj.GroupName = "Group2"
    secObj.GroupID = 2;
    secObj.UserName = "Annie L. Hunter";
    secObj.UserEmail = "ahunter@gmail.com";
    secObj.UserID = 4;
    secObjs.push(secObj);

    var secObj = new Object();
    secObj.GroupName = "Group2"
    secObj.GroupID = 2;
    secObj.UserName = "Cora J. Hunter";
    secObj.UserEmail = "cjhunter@gmail.com";
    secObj.UserID = 5;
    secObjs.push(secObj);

    var secObj = new Object();
    secObj.GroupName = "UsersGroup"
    secObj.GroupID = 3;
    secObj.UserName = "Kym Hunter";
    secObj.UserEmail = "Khunter@gmail.com";
    secObj.UserID = 6;
    secObjs.push(secObj);

    var secObj = new Object();
    secObj.GroupName = "UsersGroup"
    secObj.GroupID = 3;
    secObj.UserName = "Andrea Hunter";
    secObj.UserEmail = "ahunter@gmail.com";
    secObj.UserID = 7;
    secObjs.push(secObj);

    var secObj = new Object();
    secObj.GroupName = "UsersGroup"
    secObj.GroupID = 3;
    secObj.UserName = "Kym Hunter Jr";
    secObj.UserEmail = "KhunterII@gmail.com";
    secObj.UserID = 8;
    secObjs.push(secObj);

    return secObjs;
}

function LoadUI() {
    var securityObjs = GetSecurityDetails();
    var oldGroup = "";
    var newGroup = "";
    var htmlString = "";
    var Groups = [];
    htmlString += "<table><tr>";
    for (var a = 0; a < securityObjs.length; a++) {

        newGroup = securityObjs[a].GroupName;
        if (newGroup != oldGroup) {
            var group = new Object()
            group.GroupName = securityObjs[a].GroupName;
            group.GroupID = securityObjs[a].GroupID;
            Groups.push(group)
            oldGroup = newGroup;
        }

    }
    for (var b = 0; b < Groups.length; b++) {
        htmlString += "<td valign='top'><div><div  groupid='" + Groups[b].GroupID + "'>" + Groups[b].GroupName + "</div><div>";
        htmlString += "<ul id='" + Groups[b].GroupName + "' class='connectedSortable groups containers'>";
        for (var c = 0; c < securityObjs.length; c++) {
            if (Groups[b].GroupID == securityObjs[c].GroupID) {
                var UserName = securityObjs[c].UserName;
                var UserID = securityObjs[c].UserID;
                var UserEmail = securityObjs[c].UserEmail;

                htmlString += "<li userid='" + UserID + "' class='ui-state-default'>" + UserName + "&nbsp;(" + UserEmail + ")<a href='#' class='DeleteMe'>&nbsp;&nbsp;X&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></li>";
            }
        }
        htmlString += "</ul></div></div></td>";
    }
    htmlString += "</tr></table>";
    $("body").append(htmlString);
}
/* Issue: I can drag two items to it's destination list, but the oriignal list on recieves the first last dragged item instead of the n of items I dragged when I started.*/
$(function () {
    LoadUI();
    var cloneItem = "";
    var parentContainer = "";
    var currentContainer = "";
    var isFound = false;
    $(".groups").on('click', 'li', function (e) {
        if (e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey) {
            $(this).toggleClass("selected");
        } else {
            $(this).addClass("selected").siblings().removeClass('selected');
        }
    }).sortable({
        connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
        delay: 150,
        revert: 0,
        //helper: 'clone',
        helper: function (e, item) {

            var helper = $('<li/>');
            /**/
            if (!item.hasClass('selected')) {
                item.addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
            }
            var elements = item.parent().children('.selected').clone();
            item.data('multidrag', elements).siblings('.selected').remove();
            return helper.append(elements);
        },
        start: function (event, ui) {
            //alert("start")
            parentContainer = "#" + this.id;
            //ui.item.siblings(".selected").appendTo(ui.item);
        },
        remove: function (event, ui) {


        },
        receive: function (event, ui) {
            currentContainer = "#" + ui.item.context.parentElement.id;

            var identicalItemCount = $(currentContainer).children('li:contains(' + ui.item.text() + ')').length;

            if (identicalItemCount > 1) {
                $(currentContainer).children('li:contains(' + ui.item.text() + ')').first().remove();
            }
        },
        stop: function (event, ui) {

            ui.item.after(ui.item.data('multidrag')).remove();

            /* clone the dropped li elements back to it's original container. */
            var destinationItems = $(currentContainer).find('.selected');
            var sourceItems = $(parentContainer).find('.selected');


            $(currentContainer).children('.selected').clone(true, true).appendTo(parentContainer);
            /* Remove the '.selected' class from the li items after they were added.*/
            //$(parentContainer).find("li").removeClass("selected");
            //$(currentContainer).find("li").removeClass("selected");

            var copyParentContainer = $(parentContainer).find("li");

        }
    });

    $(".DeleteMe").click(function () {
        $(this).context.parentElement.remove();
    });
    //$("li").click(function() {
    //  $(this).toggleClass("selected");
    // });
});
```

```
/*[CSS]*/
 .containers {
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    width: 300px;
    min-height: 20px;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px 0 0 0;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
.selected {
    color:red;
}
.containers li {
    margin: 0 5px 5px 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    width: 300px;
```

```
[html]
<body></body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit: Try this**

```
$(function () {
    LoadUI();
    $(".groups").on('click', 'li', function (e) {
        if (e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey) {
            $(this).toggleClass("selected");
        } else {
            $(this).addClass("selected").siblings().removeClass('selected');
        }
    }).sortable({
        connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
        delay: 150,
        revert: 0,
        helper: function (e, item) {
            var helper = $('<li/>');
            /**/
            if (!item.hasClass('selected')) {
                item.addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
            }
            var elements = item.parent().children('.selected').clone();
            item.data('multidrag', elements).siblings('.selected').remove();

            item.parent().append(elements.clone().removeClass('selected'));
            return helper.append(elements);
        },
        start: function (event, ui) {

        },
        stop: function (event, ui) {
            ui.item.data('multidrag').each(function () {
                $(this).removeClass('selected');
                if ($(ui.item).parent().find('[userid="' + $(this).attr("userid") + '"]').length > 1) {
                    $(ui.item).remove();
                }
            });
            ui.item.after(ui.item.data('multidrag')).remove();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Close...Based on your solution, I loose the ability to drag multiple items from one container to another. I need to keep the ability to drag multiples items from one container to another, remove the '.selected' class from item that have been dropped and prevent duplication (which I think you have addressed in your proposed solution)

Comment: Good point, I completely missed that. Try the edited solution, hopefully this will work for you

Comment: I think we're very close......Let me try to figure it out the rest and I'll post my solution...